# Is there any timeout period for PagingState in Cassandra?

Tags: java, cassandra, pagination

I'm working with Cassandra in Java for some time and found that we can limit the size of result set and by storing paging state from application side, we can reuse that page state on the same statement to get data from the last record of previous response. For example,

```
ResultSet resultSet = session.execute("your query");
PagingState pagingState = resultSet.getExecutionInfo().getPagingState();
```

we can use this pagingState variable to get next batch of records(based on fetch size setted) like below.

```
Statement st = new SimpleStatement("your query");
st.setPagingState(pagingState);
ResultSet rs = session.execute(st);
```

This means that Cassandra stores a link to its indexed data with paging state. I want to understand if there exists any timeout period till the page state is kept inside cassandra database or it keeps the links(paging state) alive untill the session is closed. I have gone through Cassandra's official documentation, still could not find any.

Answer (score 5):

Fortunately, there is no timeout associated with paging state, with one small caveat.   Without going into too much detail as things may change between versions, internally paging state holds an MD5 of the query text, the page size, the protocol version used, and a reference to the clustering key(s) that represent the last row read (and also the partition key if the query spans partitions).

However, it is not guaranteed that paging state will work across protocol versions, as described in the [java driver manual for paging](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/paging/):

> Due to internal implementation details, PagingState instances are not portable across native protocol versions. This could become a problem in the following scenario:
>
> - you’re using the driver 2.0.x and Cassandra 2.0.x, and therefore native protocol v2;
> - a user bookmarks a link to your web service that contains a serialized paging state;
> - you upgrade your server stack to use the driver 2.1.x and Cassandra 2.1.x, so you’re now using protocol v3;
> - the user tries to reload their bookmark, but the paging state was serialized with protocol v2, so trying to reuse it will fail.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  So., if session is not closed, paging state info will remain in data Base forever?

Comment: All of the state is in the PagingState data itself.  Cassandra doesn't hold any state for the paging so the Session can be closed and the PagingState will still be in tact.  This is why it can be reused forever (with same protocol version), and why when you query a C* node that has never seen that query before, it is still able to know where to page from.  I.E. if you query Node A and it returns a paging state, if you then send the query to Node B with that paging state, it will still work since all state is contained in the paging state.